# Hyper-V host tuned off virtual machines when shutting down - how to find cause?

Tags: virtual-machine, shutdown, hyper-v

We recently moved our Hyper-V host machine to our own small data-centre with our own small UPS and I was tasked with setting everything up.

The UPS configuration is fine. What I found worrying is that when shutting down a Windows 2008 SP2 machine running Hyper-V with lots of VMs, not all of those VMs were saved correctly. Some were, some weren't. There should be plenty of HDD space for the state files and I can manually save each of those machines without a problem.

How can I try and debug this? All VMs are configured to be saved on host shutdown, so what I observed shouldn't have happened. I thought about looking through the event log, but the Windows log gets really long really fast, so without a starting point I'm not sure where I should be looking (and what for).

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are the same VMs not saved correctly each time?

Comment: @Ramhound This is our main work environment, so I'm a bit reluctant to take it down for prolonged periods of time for tests. Without it we don't have internet access or can't log work hours. I'd love to test it again, but until then my answer is "I have no idea".

Comment: There a reason you are not shutting down the VMs before you shutdown the Server in the Hyper-V role ?

Comment: Are you sure the VMs are configured to save state?  Shutting down is one of the configurable options, and recommended for DCs, and Exchange.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm testing the case when there's an AC power failure and the UPS sends a shutdown signal to the host.

Comment: @Zoredache The "save state" is the default setting. We don't have any Exchange servers, and the state saving is temporary at best (for any DCs), as it's only for the case of a power failure, so it shouldn't cause issues. In any case, I've noticed the problem because after starting the host we didn't have internet access - our Forefront TMG VM wasn't saved correctly and I had to wait for it to boot up fully.

Comment: I think it would be easier to find an answer to the problem by answering other question first.

When shutting down the Host Machine, does't this machine gives enough time to VMs to be saved/shut down properly?

In case of many VMs it may take a while before they all save their states or shut down correctly as all of them will start doing some maintenance at this same time (flushing files, closing connections, you name it)

Does the host machine waits for VMs to shut down?

Comment: @aristo Good question. I have no idea, really. I expected the HyperV service, when issued a stop, to wait for the VMs to save / shut down (properly). Is there a way to check if this is true?

Comment: Apparently, during shut down Windows waits for services (i.e. Hyper-V) to shut down for a while. A service can request also some additional time as well but at some point it will pull the rug from under its feet (like someone nicely described it somewhere). Seems you need to make sure all VMs shut down in reasonable time or Windows will at some point turn them off (equivalent of long press of power button)

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx